# .gitignore: How to indicate end of line

Tags: git

I would like Git to ignore object files generated by C++. These are named

```
<my_file>.o
```

On the other hand, I do not want Git to ignore files named

```
blah.omg.ext
```

where the name includes '.o' followed by more stuff. In a normal regular expression I would write the pattern to be ignored something like *.o$ where $ indicates end of line. The .gitignore documentation makes no mention of end of line, nor does it mention regular expressions. Is it possible to force Git to ignore object files named *.o, while not ignoring files named *.o?

Here is the link to the documentation I have mentioned above:

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Patterns in `.gitignore` files are *glob* patterns, not regular expressions. Shell glob names are, in effect, anchored at file or directory name boundaries: `a*b` matches file or directory `axyb`, but not `caxyb` nor `axybc`. Note that `*` in a glob pattern is very different from `*` in a regular expression, too; and instead of `.` to match any single character, you use `?` in glob expressions. Git's globs also handle `**`, which not all shell style glob matchers handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was curious and did a quick test and created a .gitignore like this

```
 *.o
```

Then I created two new files

```
touch foo.o
touch bar.omg
```

and did a `git status`. As expected, `foo.o` was ignored and `bar.omg` was shown as untracked.

So just add `*.o` and you're done. It will only ignore the object files (all files with `.o` extension)

Comment: You're right. I tried this with my project files and it worked. *.o files are ignored while files named *.o<more-characters> are not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to negate the second option. Something like this:

```
<my_file>.o
!<my_file>.omg.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

My `.gitignore` ignores `*.user` files.

But now, everything below `Foo.Modules.User` is ignored as well. When i run `git check-ignore -v Foo.Modules.User.csproj` i get the following result

```
Foo.Modules.User.csproj
.gitignore:6:*.user     Foo.Modules.User.csproj
```

Thats actually a strange behaviour. Any hints on that?